# Python function for coordinates

Tags: python, function, class, pygame, coordinates

I've programmed mummies into my game and I want them to follow my player. I want to make a function that I can use to apply to all enemies that I choose to create, but the one that I have is not quite working. The mummies will spawn in, but they won't follow the player. How can I alter the function to allow it to work?

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
import time
from pygame import mixer

screenx = 800
screeny = 600

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#PICTURES
#name = pygame.display.set_caption('Brutal Survival')
#win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenx,screeny))
#player_right = pygame.image.load('maincharright.png')
#player_left = pygame.image.load('maincharleft.png')
#player_up = pygame.image.load('maincharup.png')
#player_down = pygame.image.load('mainchardown.png')
#background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
#mummychar = pygame.image.load('mummychar.png')

randomspawnabove = (random.randint(0, screenx), -100)
randomspawnbelow = (random.randint(0, screenx), (screeny + 100))
randomspawnleft = (-100, random.randint(0, screeny))
randomspawnright = ((screenx + 100), random.randint(0, screeny))

enemyalive = True
multiplier = 2
level = 1
nextlevel = True
spawn = True
up = True
down = False
left = False
right = False
run = True


class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.alive = True
        self.vel = 5

class enemy():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.alive = False
        self.vel = 2

def enemyfollow(self):
    if self.alive == True and self.x > mainChar.x:
        self.x = self.x - self.vel
    if self.alive == True and self.x < mainChar.x:
        self.x = self.x + self.vel
    if self.alive == True and self.y > mainChar.y:
        self.y = self.y - self.vel
    if self.alive == True and self.y < mainChar.y:
        self.y = self.y + self.vel


def redrawScreen():
    pygame.display.update()
    if run == True:
        win.blit(background, (0,0))
    if up == True and left == False and right == False and down == False:
        win.blit(player_up, (mainChar.x, mainChar.y))
    if up == False and left == False and right == False and down == True:
        win.blit(player_down, (mainChar.x, mainChar.y))
    if up == False and left == False and right == True and down == False:
        win.blit(player_right, (mainChar.x, mainChar.y))
    if up == False and left == True and right == False and down == False:
        win.blit(player_left, (mainChar.x, mainChar.y))
    if enemyalive == True:
        win.blit(mummychar, (mummy1.x, mummy1.y))
        enemyfollow(mummy1)


mainChar = player(screenx/2 - 30, screeny/2, 60, 60)
maxenemies = (level * multiplier)
mummy_Spawn = [randomspawnleft, randomspawnright, randomspawnabove, randomspawnbelow]
mummy1 = enemy(*random.choice(mummy_Spawn), 50, 50)

while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()

    for x in range(maxenemies):
        Enemies.append(enemy(*random.choice(mummy_Spawn), 50, 50))

    if nextlevel == True:
        if level >= 1:
            enemyalive = True

    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False
        pygame.quit()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y - mainChar.vel
        up = True
        down = False
        left = False
        right = False
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y + mainChar.vel
        down = True
        left = False
        up = False
        right = False
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x + mainChar.vel
        right = True
        left = False
        up = False
        down = False
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x - mainChar.vel
        left = True
        right = False
        down = False
        up = False
    if (mainChar.y + mainChar.height) > screeny:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y - 5
    if mainChar.y < 0:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y + 5
    if mainChar.x < 0:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x + 5
    if (mainChar.x + mainChar.width) > screenx:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x - 5

    redrawScreen()
```

Comment: This is not a MCVE example as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
When I tried to run it I encountered an error `pygame.error: Couldn't open maincharright.png`. You should reduce your example to the relevant code

Comment: is `enemyfollow()` part of `class enemy` ?

Comment: @Kingsley no. If I put enemyfollow() in class enemy, I get an error: NameError: name 'enemyfollow' is not defined. I'm not really sure how to call the function if it's in the class

Comment: @Kingsley yes it is because it takes `self` as an argument. Either the OP incorrectly indented for his post, or incorrectly indented within his main script

Comment: @LukeSchwab You can't just call `enemyfollow()` if it is a *method* of a class. You would have to call `instance.enemyfollow()` after you create an *instance* of your class.

Comment: @Reedinationer. I've done this, and the problem persists. There aren't any errors, but the enemies aren't moving towards the player. They are just standing still

Answer (score 0):

part of if statement was if `self == True`, but `self` was False

Answer (score 0):

So the Mummy of object needs to *follow* the Player object.  Refining this problem description further:

> Every time a Mummy moves, it should be in the *direction* of the Player.

So how do we do that?

Imagine we draw an arrow from the position of the Mummy to the Player.  This would define the direction the Mummy should move.  In formal (mathematical) terms this is a direction *vector*.  To work out the direction vector, we work out the line between the two points, then *normalise* it by dividing by it's length.

The upshot of this we get a simple `x` and `y` *unit vector*, the components of which can be multiplied by the object's speed to obtain it's next position.

In the example below, there are 3 sprites which will move toward the position of the mouse.  The important part is the `MySprite.update()` function.  This grabs the mouse position (in your case this is the Player), and the sprite's location (Mummy position), using these two points to compute the vector.  Once the vector is determined, the components are used along with the sprite's speed to calculate the next position.  I keep the position internally as a float, so that small angles of change and low speeds are handled nicer.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH=400
WINDOW_HEIGHT=400

BLACK = (50,50,50)


class MySprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, filename ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image  = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.rect   = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed  = random.randrange( 1, 3 )
        self.xfloat = random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_WIDTH )
        self.yfloat = random.randrange( 0, WINDOW_HEIGHT )
        self.rect.center = ( int( self.xfloat ), int( self.yfloat ) )

    def update( self ):
        # Re-compute our new movement vector based on the mouse every update
        # so we always move towards the mouse
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if ( mouse_pos != (0, 0) ):
            my_pos    = [ self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery ]
            dir_vector= self.normalisedMovementVector( my_pos, mouse_pos )
            x_delta = self.speed * dir_vector[0]
            y_delta = self.speed * dir_vector[1]
            self.xfloat += x_delta
            self.yfloat += y_delta
            self.rect.center = ( int(self.xfloat), int(self.yfloat) )

    def lineLength( self, pointa, pointb ):
        """ Return the length of a line between the two points, in pixels """
        x1,y1 = pointa
        x2,y2 = pointb
        # length = sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
        x_squared = (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)
        y_squared = (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)
        length = math.sqrt( x_squared + y_squared )
        return length

    def normalisedMovementVector( self, pointa, pointb ):
        """ Return a normalised vector between to points """
        # offset it from (0,0) to make calculations simpler
        # since it's a *direction* the actual positions don't matter
        pointb = (pointb[0]-pointa[0], pointb[1]-pointa[1])
        length = self.lineLength( (0,0), pointb )
        # normalise it (divide by it's own length)
        if ( length > 0 ):
            x = pointb[0] / length
            y = pointb[1] / length
            move_vector = ( x , y )
        else:
            # catch division by zero
            move_vector = ( 0, 0 )
        return move_vector




### MAIN
# Initialise the window
pygame.init()
SURFACE_TYPE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE_TYPE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Follow Mouse")

# Add some sprites
SPRITES = pygame.sprite.Group()
for i in range(3):
    s = MySprite( 'tiny_alien.png' )
    SPRITES.add( s ) # Put in sprites group

# tick tick tick
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Main loop
done = False
while not done:

    # Move the sprites (nd checks for collisions)
    SPRITES.update()

    # Handle user input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE_TYPE )

    # Paint the screen
    WINDOW.fill( BLACK )
    SPRITES.draw( WINDOW )
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )

# Bye
pygame.quit()
```

Any PNG image can be substituted for `tiny_alien.png`.

[image: follow_mouse.gif]

(Animated .gif is a bit jerky, but on-screen it's smooth)

Comment: This approach works if there's no obstacles or if the mummies are dumb and always charge straight towards you despite any obstacles. If there are obstacles, and you want your mummies to go around obstacles, you'll need to use path finding algorithm like A* (A-star).

Comment: @LieRyan - Indeed.  But it was good enough for Berzerk ;)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berzerk_(video_game)

Answer (score 0):

This version of your code works.  I think the main problem is a combination of `enemy.alive` defaults to `False`, and I'm not sure on the re-drawing order.

Since I had to replace the bitmaps with some of my own, I made further changes to constant-sized parameters - in particular the 50x50 size, but there were others too.

It took quite a few changes before it would work for me, and I lost track a bit.

```
import random
import pygame
import sys
import time
from pygame import mixer

screenx = 800
screeny = 600

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#PICTURES
name = pygame.display.set_caption('Brutal Survival')
win = pygame.display.set_mode((screenx,screeny))
player_right = pygame.image.load('maincharright.png')
player_left = pygame.image.load('maincharleft.png')
player_up = pygame.image.load('maincharup.png')
player_down = pygame.image.load('mainchardown.png')
background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')
mummychar = pygame.image.load('mummychar.png')

# stretch background to fit window
background = pygame.transform.smoothscale( background, ( screenx, screeny) )

randomspawnabove = (random.randint(0, screenx), -100)
randomspawnbelow = (random.randint(0, screenx), (screeny + 100))
randomspawnleft = (-100, random.randint(0, screeny))
randomspawnright = ((screenx + 100), random.randint(0, screeny))

enemyalive = True
multiplier = 2
level = 1
nextlevel = True
spawn = True
up = True
down = False
left = False
right = False
run = True


class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.alive = True
        self.vel = 5

class enemy():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x      = x
        self.y      = y
        self.width  = width
        self.height = height
        self.alive  = True
        self.vel    = 2

    def enemyfollow(self, player_pos):
        play_x, play_y = player_pos
        if self.alive == True and self.x > play_x:
            self.x = self.x - self.vel
        elif self.alive == True and self.x < play_x:
            self.x = self.x + self.vel
        if self.alive == True and self.y > play_y:
            self.y = self.y - self.vel
        elif self.alive == True and self.y < play_y:
            self.y = self.y + self.vel


def redrawScreen( player_image, Enemies ):
    win.blit(background, (0,0))
    win.blit(player_image, (mainChar.x, mainChar.y))
    for e in Enemies:
        if e.alive == True:
            win.blit(mummychar, (e.x, e.y))
    pygame.display.update()


mainChar     = player(screenx/2 - 30, screeny/2, 60, 60)
maxenemies   = (level * multiplier)
mummy_Spawn  = [randomspawnleft, randomspawnright, randomspawnabove, randomspawnbelow]
player_image = player_left

# Create some enemies:
Enemies = []
for x in range(maxenemies):
    Enemies.append(enemy(random.randrange(0, screenx), random.randrange(0, screeny), mummychar.get_rect().width, mummychar.get_rect().height))

while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    for i in range(maxenemies):
        Enemies[i].enemyfollow( (mainChar.x, mainChar.y) )

    if nextlevel == True:
        if level >= 1:
            enemyalive = True

    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        run = False
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y - mainChar.vel
        player_image = player_up
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y + mainChar.vel
        player_image = player_down
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x + mainChar.vel
        player_image = player_right
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x - mainChar.vel
        player_image = player_left

    if (mainChar.y + mainChar.height) > screeny:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y - 5
    if mainChar.y < 0:
        mainChar.y = mainChar.y + 5
    if mainChar.x < 0:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x + 5
    if (mainChar.x + mainChar.width) > screenx:
        mainChar.x = mainChar.x - 5

    redrawScreen( player_image, Enemies )

pygame.quit()
```